# Issue with image module on Python3

Tags: python-3.x, import

This is my 1st question (I'm trying to learn Python as a starting point into programming)

I'm on my second Basic Python class, and have an issue with an assignment.

I'm on the "Image Processing" chapter and I'm trying to run the following:
#I have a MAC running Big Sur 11.3.1

```
import image

p = image.Pixel(45, 76, 200)
print(p.getRed())
p.setRed(66)
print(p.getRed())
p.setBlue(p.getGreen())
print(p.getGreen(), p.getBlue())
```

I had to install "image" and "PIL" (I was unable to import them at first)

I run the following (to install them)

```
python3 -m pip install image
python3 -m pip install PIL
```

I tried to import the image module (afterwards)

I've tried:

```
import image
```

and also:

```
from PIL import Image
```

But when I try the following, I keep getting an error:

```
bash-3.2$ python3
Python 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:10:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import image
>>> p = image.Pixel(45, 76, 200)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'image' has no attribute 'Pixel'
>>>
```

or,

```
bash-3.2$ python3
Python 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:10:52) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> p = image.Pixel(45, 76, 200)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'image' is not defined
>>>
```

I'm not sure if I didn't install/uploaded the modules properly

I've been trying to look this up on-line, but I haven't had much luck.

any help/assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`.Pixel` is supposed to be called on an image object to give you the value of a pixel. You don't have an image object right now.

You've imported the modules, but where is the actual image itself? You need to either create a new image or read one from a file.

If you `from PIL import Image`, you can use `Image.new(mode, size, color)` to make a new blank image. Check out this resource for an example: https://gethowstuff.com/create-new-image-python-pil/